# Better way to profile?

Tags: php, profile

Is there a better way to profile code then:

```
$start1 = microtime(TRUE);
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
 {
    //do something
 }
$time1 = microtime(TRUE) - $start1;
```

Comment: if your going to profile like that then move your count outside of the time interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xdebug or Zend Debugger if you have some difficulty to install Xdebug.

Their profiler will time everything for you without any modification of your code.

http://www.xdebug.org/

http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt

http://devzone.zend.com/article/2899-Profiling-PHP-Applications-With-xdebug - a serie of tutorials about xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

Without using an external tool, I would say you've done the best you can.

If you want to use a tool built for the purpose, the other answers are dead-on.